# Laravel testing, get JSON content

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

In Laravel's unit test, I can test a JSON API like that:

```
$this->post('/user', ['name' => 'Sally'])
    ->seeJson([
        'created' => true,
    ]);
```

But what if I want to use the response. How can I get the JSON response (as an array) using `$this->post()`?

Comment: `$this->getResponse()->getContent()` might do the trick.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Currently, in `5.3` this is working...

```php
$content = $this->get('/v1/users/1')->response->getContent();
```

However, it does break the chain since `response` returns the response and not the test runner.  So, you should make your chainable assertions before fetching the response, like so...

```php
$content = $this->get('/v1/users/1')->seeStatusCode(200)->response->getContent();
```

Comment: Using in Laravel 7, ``decodeResponseJson`` is the right method. This returns string.

Comment: How can i see what methods are available for `response`?

Answer (score 99):

Proper way to get the content is:

```
$content = $this->get('/v1/users/1')->decodeResponseJson();
```

Comment: I agree. Works in 5.4.

Comment: Works in 5.7 too.

Comment: 6.3.3: throws an exception that decodeResponseJson() has been deprecated.  Would check the doc but we all know how pointless that is...

Comment: The full list of methods you can use is in `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse` class (Laravel 6 lts), in addition to Docs.

Comment: Works for 8.40 too

Answer (score 17):

As at Laravel 8, this worked for me.
I was returning an automatically generated field (balance) after the POST request has created the entity.
The response was in the structure `{"attributes":{"balance":12345}}`

```
$response = $this->postJson('api/v1/authors', [
    'firstName' => 'John',
    'lastName' => 'Doe',
])->assertStatus(201);

$balance = $response->decodeResponseJson()['attributes']['balance'];
```

`decodeResponseJson` will pick the response and transform it to an array for manipulation.
Using `getContent()` returns json and you will have to use `json_decode` on the returned data to turn it into an array.

Comment: Works in Version 8.+

Answer (score 13):

I like to use the json method when working with json, instead of ->get()

```
$data = $this->json('GET', $url)->seeStatusCode(200)->decodeResponseJson();
```

Answer (score 9):

I hit a similar problem and could not get $this->getResponse()->getContent() working with the built in $this->get() method.  I tried several variations with no success.

Instead I had to change the call to return the full http response and get the content out of that.

```
// Original (not working)
$content = $this->get('/v1/users/1')->getContent();

// New (working)
$content = $this->call('GET', '/v1/users/1')->getContent();
```

Comment: The test case doesn't have a `getContent()` method.  The `get()` method is a fluent helper that returns the test case (so you can chain multiple assertions).  The test case does have a `response` property that will return your response object (instead of the test case).  Then you can call `getContent()` on that response object.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Simple way:

```
$this->getJson('api/threads')->content()
```

Comment: Use json() here instead of content() to also json decode the response data

Comment: Also you can use getOriginalContent(), as it return in array.

Answer (score 6):

Found a better way:

```php
$response = $this->json('POST', '/order', $data);
$responseData = $response->getOriginalContent(); // saves the response as an array
$responseData['value']  // you can now access the array values
```

This method returns the response json as an array.

Answer (score 5):

Just want to share, I have used the same in `$this->json()` like:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/order', $data)->response->getContent();
```

But I added one more line to use json response and decode otherwise `decodeResponseJson()` was not working for me.

```
$json = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Might have been a version issue

Comment: Same! I prefer `json_decode($response->getContent(), true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call:

$data = $response->json();

Answer (score -1):

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/products', $data);
$data = $response->getData();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).